# AJAX Form is submitting correctly but failing to refresh form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to add twitter-esque feeds into my application by modifying the guide from Michael Hartl's book: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users

There is a "follow" button that should turn into "unfollow" or vice versa when pressed. The form is submitting successfully (If I refresh the page, it changes the button to the correct version, and the relationships are being created in the database), but the button simply fails to change to the correct version without a full page refresh.

_follow_form.html.erb (partial loaded by main view page)

```
<div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@restaurant) %>
    <%= render 'restaurants/unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'restaurants/follow' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

_follow.html.erb (follow button)

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @restaurant.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

_unfollow.html.erb (unfollow button)

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(current_user.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @restaurant.id),
             html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

Relevant controller

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(restaurant)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @restaurant }
      format.js
    end    
  end
  def destroy
    restaurant = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow(restaurant)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @restaurant }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('restaurants/unfollow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @restaurant.followers.count %>');
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('restaurants/follow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @restaurant.followers.count %>');
```

Here is the error I am getting according to Chrome:

```
NoMethodError in Relationships#destroy

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/suburblia/app/views/restaurants/_follow.html.erb where line #2 raised:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/relationships/destroy.js.erb
Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/suburblia
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change restaurant in the controller to @restaurant. Not sure why, but this worked. Any explanations would be cool!

Comment: restaurant is a local variable, @restaurant is a instance variable. Instance variables are available to use on views.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `@restaurant` is a *class instance variable* and as such it is available in your views, but `restaurant` is a *local variable*, only available within the method (i.e. action) it is defined.

Your view calls for that variable in `<%= @restaurant.followers.count %>` but since you were defining a *local variable* `restaurant`, it wasn't available to your view and you got a `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` error; that is `@restaurant` returned `nil` instead of a `Restaurant` object.

But when you changed it to `@restaurant` you made it available to your view, so no more `nil` values.